# Keep the same port number for forwarded packets

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, pppoe, ipsec

I have the following IPSEC setup:

LEFT (IPsec) <===> MID (PPP) <=ppp=> RIGHT (IPsec+PPP)

1. All running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
2. MID communicates with RIGHT in PPPoE (marked ppp).

Now...

- IPsec servers are trying to exchange Phase-1 *isakmp* keys without success.
- Packets from RIGHT to LEFT are leaving RIGHT from the *isakmp* port - UDP 500 (4500 if using NAT-T), and reach LEFT in the same port.
- Packets from LEFT to RIGHT, are leaving LEFT from the *isakmp* port, **but** MID gets the packets with *isakmp* port and **replaces** them to **port 1**. Packets are forwarded to RIGHT with source port 1, and arrive as such.
- All throughout - source and destination *addresses* are kept fine, and other than the port numbers, NAT works fine.

I tried to force MID to keep the source ports using:

- `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT -o ethX --to a.d.r.s -p udp --sport 500`
- `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT -o ethX --to a.d.r.s:500 -p udp`
- Tried masquerading with `iptables` and `ip rule`

Whatever I do - packets keep **arriving with source port 1**. According to IANA ([Reserved ports list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)) this is a Service Mux Port (?).

Ideas anyone?